# Github Pages share button jekyll

Tags: ruby, content-management-system, jekyll, github-pages

It's my wp share button `<li class="whatsapp">
          <a href='https://api.whatsapp.com/send?text={{ page.url | replace:"index.html","" | prepend: site.baseurl | prepend: site.url | uri_escape}}'>{% include whatsapp.svg %}</a>
        </li>`
but It's share my link https://localhost:4000/2017/07/17/Welcome-To-Jekyll/  but Github-pages envoriment share  as 2017/07/17/Welcome-To-Jekyll/.What's problem ?
It's my gemfile:

```
source "https://rubygems.org"
gemspec

# Ensures the proper Jekyll version is running.
gem "jekyll", "3.5.2"
gem 'jekyll-sass-converter'

# Plugins
group :jekyll_plugins do
   gem "jekyll-feed", "~> 0.9.2"
   gem 'jekyll-archives'
   gem 'jekyll-paginate'
   gem 'github-pages'
end
```

Comment: Whaaatt????! 

Comment: Sorry My English grammar is bad.